# Cannot disable CSRF security in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I want to send http request from Ruby code with these values but every time I get `CSRF verification failed`:

`http://some_domain.com?key=value&t5052&key=value&key=value`

I have this Spring configuration:

Endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, value = "/v1/notification")
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotifications(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, Object> keyValuePairs) {
     .....
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Spring convert config:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "org.rest.api.*", "org.plugin.service", "org.plugin.transactions.factory" })
@EntityScan("org.plugin.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.plugin.service")
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter);
        converters.removeIf(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(
                ((XmlMapper) createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.xml()))
                        .enable(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION)));
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json())));
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        builder.indentOutput(true);
        builder.modules(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
        builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        builder.defaultUseWrapper(false);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

But I get error:

```
<h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>    
  <p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for &#39;same-origin&#39; requests.</p>
```

I tried to disable the CSRF filter using this Spring Security configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(value = { Application.class, ContextDatasource.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.rest.api.server.*" })
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    MerchantAuthService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/notification").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

POM Configuration:

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
....
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue? Can I somehow disable this CSRF check in Spring only for `/notification`?

Comment: I dont know your project structure, but it seems ApplicationSecurityConfig is not scaned  into the applicationContext, so  "http.csrf().disable();" may not execute. Recommend that you debug program to check if it executed.

Comment: @WangKenneth ok, this is a possible idea. When I enable debug for what String I should search into the log? Only `csrf`?

Comment: just set a break point on " http.csrf().disable();" or add a log statement after " http.csrf().disable();" to check

Comment: @WangKenneth Looks like it's scanned and found: https://pastebin.com/SAXufp22

Comment: ```antMatchers("/notification")``` is right?? On your controller path is ```"/v1/notification"```

Comment: Yes, my mistake. But again it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because of the code `super.configure(http);` missing

This code works on my PC:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService myUserDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                UserDetails userDetails = null;
                try {
                    userDetails = new User("admin", "admin", getAuthorities());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return userDetails;
            }

            private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
                authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
                return authList;
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

and I can find login page will add the tag

`<input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="7a943334-47ed-4e81-b59b-445b70db080b">`

if I commented  **http.csrf().disable();**

Comment: What is the purpose of `super.configure(http);`? I found many code examples on the Internet using it but I can't find why it's used?

Comment: @PeterPenzov super.configure(http) is to invoke super class method, so here is "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure() ", you can see it's code and know what job this method did. Generally,  it's mostly like your method, such  http.httpBasic(), authorizeRequests() etc. But it's not totally similar, so you can figure out what you missed

Comment: @PeterPenzov if you don't want to invoke super class method when you over ride it , you should make sure the code in super class method you really dont need.

Comment: It might be conflict with dependencies. Why don't you  use spring-boot-starter-security?

Comment: I prefer Spring Security. How I can find if there are any conflicts?

Comment: @soyphea My demo is using ``<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>``,
and in fact spring-boot-starter-security is dependent spring-security-config, spring-security-web. My version is 4.2.5

Comment: @PeterPenzov did you fix this issue?

Comment: No. I'm still researching.